# Python - Send Credentials to a FTP site

Tags: python, selenium, ftp, web-scraping, webdriver

Newbie : The following piece of code works fine for HTTP websites.
(It opens the Chrome browser and automatically sends the login credentials to our website)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window() 

driver.get('www.example.com')

username = driver.find_element_by_id("User Name")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")

username.send_keys("admin")
password.send_keys("password")

submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-default')
submit.click()
```

However this doesn't work when we open FTP sites.
A "Authentication Required" window opens, but keys for "User Name" and "Password" fields are not sent.

Kindly suggest the changes required. Thanks

Comment: Are you finding element correctly?? Could you explain more why doesn't work?? Is there any exception??

Comment: Yes elements are found correctly. Don't know why it is working on HTTP sites only

Comment: Means problem is in sendKeys.. could you tell what is the problem with sendKeys?? Does it throw any exception or anything else??

Comment: No. There is no error shown. The FTP link opens in the browser and execution halts. (User Name and Password don't get entered)

Comment: However, when the same code is executed for a HTTP link, the URL is opened, User Name and Password are automatically entered and  Submit button is also clicked, getting us to the desired webpage.

Comment: Ok you can try here using `execute_script()` ..see provided answer and let me know.